# Applications to ...?

Tags: prepositions, mathematics

I want to express in that something has applications in a related field.

Is *applications **to** partial differential equations* correct or is is necessary to change the preposition?

Comment: clarity needed!

Comment: Are you asking which of _"applications **to** partial differential equations"_ and/or _"applications **in** partial differential equations"_ is correct?  If so, the answer is that both are used, and (at least in my ear) there isn't much difference between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *in.*

> This has applications in [the 
>   field/area of] partial differential equations.

Comment: I'm not very sure, but it sounds like the OP's trying to phrase it as *Partial differential equations have applications in [some fields].* -- I agree with the preposition *in*, anyway.

Comment: Interesting. To me it seems most likely readable as *Is "applications to partial differentials" correct, or is it "applications for" or "applications to".